# QGIS Labeling- str() and int()

Tags: qgis, labeling

I am new to QGIS (ESRI shop at work).
I am attemping to concatenate fields in the label expression

```
field1 = number
field2 = number
```

label expression I tired but fails

```
str(field1) + " - " + str(field2)
```

it says its not valid. This would work in ArcMap... how is it different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change three things about your query:

- The conversion to String is done by `to_string` rather than `str`
- Strings are surrounded with `'` rather than `"`
- Field names are surrounded with `"`

So your query should look something like this:

`to_string("field1") + ' - ' + to_string("field2")`

Comment: Shouldn't it be: to_string("field1") || ' - ' || to_string("field2")

Comment: Yes, maybe that would be nicer, since it's proper SQL. It works both in QGIS, though.

Comment: Cool. Must be a new feature. Back in my day (1.8) we had to use the double bar.

Comment: Yep, seems like it. https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog260/index.html#feature-additional-expressions-types-and-options

Answer (score 4):

You can use the concatenate operator `||` or the `concat` function (under strings).

Comment: still says invalid... field1 + concat(" -" + field2)

Comment: concat('-',field2)